# change color of a paragraph with php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make a management panel for a web page.
So first i wrote an input type to get the color from it:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<?php $color = $_REQUEST['test']; ?>
</form>
```

and change color of a paragraph:

```
<p style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>">Hello</p>
```

But it doesnt work, Whats wrong?
Im pretty new with php, please help me with this.

Comment: Help you with what exactly?

Comment: Use PHP superglobal to get the form value: <?php $color = $_POST['test']; ?>

Comment: @pivemi I think you're on the right track, but without a method specified in the `<form>` it's probably going to be `$_GET` rather than `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **$_POST superglobal** to get the value of the **input element**. Example:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

NB: as Don't Panic pointed out in a comment, make sure to add `method="post"` to the `form` element.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$color = $_POST['test']; 

echo '<p style="color: ' . $color . ';">Hello</p>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not set the `method` attribute for your form, so it uses the default `GET`. If you use `$_GET['test']` you will be able to get the value like you expect.

To do so you could try:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <?php
        // use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST.
        $color = $_GET['test']
    ?>
</form>

<p style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>">Hello</p>
```